# Connect Google Places Api ( rating stars)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-places-api, swift4

The basic idea of the ViewController is to show the name of the restaurant and its rating stars. The name of the restaurants comes from my API in JSON and the rating is from Google places API.

I first get the names from the server:

```
 func getData (){
    let urlStr = "http://myserver.com/api/"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get ,encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

        if let value : AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject {
            let shops = JSON(value)
            for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in  shops["families"] {
                if subJson["disable"] == "0"{

                    let shopName = subJson["name"].stringValue
                    self.performSereach(shopName: shopName)//do search

                  // take the name and
            var info = Shops(shopname: shopName, 
    Logo: logoString, family_id: familiy_id , design : designImage)
           // save the data to show in TableVIewCell
```

Now I perform a search in Google places with the link

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=\(shopName)+in+SanFrancisco&key=MyKey
```

The function to do the search :

```
 func performSereach(shopName : String ) {
    let formattedString = shopName.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
    let urlStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=\(formattedString)+in+ SanFrancisco&key=MyKey"

    Alamofire.request(urlStr).responseJSON { response in
        if let value : AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject {

            let data = JSON(value)
            for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in  data["results"] {


                print(subJson["rating"])
                 print(subJson["name"])
```

But when I do this I feel like I'm doing it wrong because:

1- There are so many Starbucks in my area so the response will have more than one rating ( in this case I would like to take the first one) And the print statements prints all the Starbucks and its rating

2- how can I connect the shopName with its rating star at the end of the search in `Shops` ?

`Shops` is:

```
import Foundation

class Shops {
var _familiy_id: String?
var _logo : String?
var _design: String?
var _rate : Int


var _shopname : String?
        var rate : Int{
    return _rate
}
var familiy_id : String{
    return _familiy_id!
}

   var shopname : String{
    return _shopname!
}
var Logo : String{
    return _logo!
}

var design : String {
    return _design!
}

init(shopname : String , Logo : String , family_id : String, design : String , rate : Int) {

    self._shopname = shopname
           self._logo = Logo
    self._familiy_id = family_id
    self._design = design
    self._rate = rate
}
```

}